# jQuery attribute or hardcoded attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

How are the following two different?

*a. Using jQuery*

```
$(iframe).attr("id", "youtube-player"+i);
$(iframe).attr("enablejsapi", 1);
$(iframe).attr("origin", "http://0:8080");

//DOM result
<iframe id="youtube-player0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoID" enablejsapi="1" origin="http://0:8080">
```

*b. Hardcoded*

```
<iframe id="youtube-player0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoID?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://0:8080">
```

Google just added requirement to add "origin" attribute to the src. I wanted to do it with the first method, but it seems only the second method works. I am confused because the first method works perfectly without adding `origin` attribute. Do those two ways actually bring out different results?

Comment: The second method markup is invalid, check the double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`origin` and `enablejsapi` are not a separate attribute. Use following;

```
$(iframe).attr("id", "youtube-player"+i);
$(iframe).attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoID?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://0:8080");
```